# vhdx image for Windows 10 (with UEFI partition) is not booting if secure boot is enabled

Tags: uefi, hyper-v, efi, vhd, secure-boot

I have a vhdx image of a windows installation with UEFI partition. When i try to boot it on a hyper-v, it goes to system recovery mode all the time. When i try to disable secure boot option from hyper-v, it comes up properly.

I tried the same procedure with windows 8 and it works fine. what might be the reason for it? Is there any workaround so that I can boot it with secure boot enabled?

Comment: What generation is the VM? See these references for bootloader problems : [article 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dai/2014/04/10/using-vhd-native-boot-with-uefi-firmware-bcdedit-vs-bcdboot/) and [thread 2](http://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/28913-cant-native-boot-hyper-v-generation-2-vhdx.html).

Comment: Hyper-V Manager - Microsoft Corporation - Version: 10.0.10586.0

Comment: I mean if they are generation 1 or 2 (see [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ausoemteam/2015/04/21/deciding-when-to-use-generation-1-or-generation-2-virtual-machines-with-hyper-v/) for the difference).

Comment: Windows 10 has UEFI partition. I am using generation 2 in hyperV (I think it is necessary for UEFI based partition).

Comment: Please comment on my two links above, so we can continue to examine the problem.

Comment: Actually it is happening after our driver installation. main problem is that vhdx for windows 2016 Technical preview is booting but the same is not booting for windows 10. Both contains the driver. in order to boot windows 10, I have to disable secure boot in hyperV. bcdedit is same for both vhdx files. I tried to debug but if secure boot is disable ( needed for debugging) it is booting without problem. How can i identify and make sure tht my kernel module is the problem or thr is something else?

Comment: @Durgesh If this weren't a VM, I'd say that your HD doesn't have a GPT defined or EFI to see the bootloader for what to boot to via UEFI, & you have Windows installed on the disk with a MBR type of setup. Maybe enabling the Secure Boot feature of UEFI takes it to recovery so you can create GPT, etc. so it knows what to do. Otherwise, disable Secure Boot and it is booting to the MBR rather than using some UEFI feature/option for where to boot.You may already know all this but I thought I'd at least drop you a comment and mention the obvious--not too sure about VMs & Secure Boot myself though.

Comment: @Durgesh  - What you want to know, based on your bounty description, wouldn't really answer the question you have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that Windows 10 & Windows 2012 R2 support Generation 1 (same as previous versions of Hyper-V) and Generation 2 (new functionality) virtual machines.

Generation 2 is required for:
 - Booting from SCSI HDD & DVDs
 - Secure Boot
 - UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) firmware support

Guest OS's supported under Gen 2 are:
 - Windows Server 2012 R2
 - Windows Server 2012
 - 64-bit versions of Windows 8, 8.1 & 10 (64-bit-only UEFI firmware)

The firmware only starts the bootloader when its signature has been signed by a trusted authority that is registered in the UEFI database.

Comment: I understand that. My doubt is - in what case VHDX may fail only for Win10 UEFI but not for Win8 UEFI? And how can I get and debug memory for the same? is there any way that i can check the failure dump of Vhdx?

Comment: @Durgesh Does your computer support Secure Boot?

Comment: It is HyperV. It has option to enable or disable secure boot.